# Python rdflib Nesting elements

Tags: python, rdflib

I have an existing rdf Graph that I want to modify. I want to add the info in the **n** variable.

```
# source graph
g = source.graph

#new entry
n = (URIRef(obj.pid), URIRef('info:symplectic/symplectic-elements:def/model#hasPublicUrl'), URIRef('http://itemlocation.com'))

#add to graph
g.add(n)

#save back to source
source.graph = g
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
   xmlns:fedora-model="info:fedora/fedora-system:def/model#"
   xmlns:ns1="info:symplectic/symplectic-elements:def/model#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="info:fedora/sympOE:mq5zf">
    <fedora-model:hasModel rdf:resource="info:fedora/emory-control:PublishedArticle-1.0"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="sympOE:mq5zf">
    <ns1:hasPublicUrl rdf:resource="http://itemlocation.com"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Everything is almost correct but I want it to be different in two ways:

1. I want there to only be one rdf:Description section that contains both entries.
2. I want the **ns1** alias to be **symp**

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want there to only be one rdf:Description section that contains both entries.

You seem to have two URIs here `info:fedora/sympOE:mq5zf` and `sympOE:mq5zf`.

Try rewriting your new entry line to:

```
uri = URIRef('info:fedora/' + obj.pid)
g.add(
  (uri, URIRef('info:symplectic/symplectic-elements:def/model#hasPublicUrl'), URIRef('http://itemlocation.com'))
)
```

> I want the ns1 alias to be symp

You will want to bind the namespace to the graph.  See examples at the bottom of [this page](http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gettingstarted.html).

It would look something like:

```
from rdflib import Namespace
ns = Namespace('http://localhost/symp#')
g.bind('symp', ns)
```